# Django - Apache Server Error (500) when uploading/saving file

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am attempting to deploy a Django site that has the ability to upload a file and then modify that file. It works 100% on the dev server, however after deploying it with Apache I am running into problems. The Server Error (500) happens on the indicated line in my views.py. What am I doing wrong? My problem is probably not understanding the save() method, however I could not find any info/documentation that helped me.

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formU = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formU.is_valid():
            f = request.FILES['myFile']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            set_file_name(str(f))
            fs.save(str(f), f) # where error occurs
```

Since everything works fine under the dev server, I assumed it would be a media file thing but (I think) all looks good there.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**proj.conf**

```
Alias /media /home/4rsenal/f_proj/media
<Directory /home/4rsenal/f_proj/media>
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: If it was working on the dev server, it's probably not a Python error. I think you have a bad configuration of your virtualhost in proj.conf. Or you just forget to open rights on your folders ?

Comment: When you have `DEBUG = True`, it shows you a hell of debugging information when something like this happens. When you have `DEBUG = False`, it emails you that information. If you haven't setup email properly, a quick-and-dirty way is to set `DEBUG=True` in production to check out what's going on. Eventually, however, you will need to setup emailing correctly by setting the `EMAIL_*` settings. See also https://djangodeployment.com/2017/01/18/why-does-django-not-email-me-the-500-internal-server-error/ to fool-proof these settings.

Comment: Yup that's it. @GrandGTO it was a permissions thing on the media folder which I saw with setting DEBUG = True (did not know you can do that in production). If either of you want to post answer below, I'll accept it as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was working on the dev server, it's probably not a Python error. I think you have a bad configuration of your virtualhost in proj.conf. Or you just forget to open rights on your folders ?

Comment: For further discussion of access rights of the Apache user, see the documentation at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user